# Customizing a project library in Android

Tags: android

I'm using [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) library project in my Android application. But I need to make some customization for it.

For example, if I need a EditText instead of the provided TextView, what is the best practice to customize the library for my needs without writing code in the Project Library?

I made this customization by defining in the library's actionbar.xml layout a EditText instead of TextView, but I don't like this approach.

Do you have any guidelines, tutorials that could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your special case I would suggest to use original compatibility's-package [actionBar](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html).

But to answer your question: you could always extend classes from the Library, which I think is the best practice if the library should kept untouched. Overriding Methods which you want to change their behavior keeps anything clean. You do the exact same every time you extend android-sdk classes, which you cannot change like you want.

In the case of changing layouts I'm not quite shure. I think I can remember that if the lib has an actionbar.xml and you have an actionbar.xml inside your project, too, yours will win. just like an "overriding layouts" feature